# Find column in VBA and sort

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

Hi there I'm trying to create a macro to make it easier to sort data exported from a robot

The trouble is the columns can change places due to the way in which the robot does the testing

Many of the columns are useless and so I have made a macro to hide the unused columns and now I would like to add a macro that sorts these remaining 4 columns in Ascending order but I just can't crack it

So far I have

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("A1:BR1").Cells
    If c.Value = "Plate Name (barcode)" Or c.Value = "Measurement Date" Or c.Value = "Measurement profile" Or c.Value = "pH" Or c.Value = "Count" Or c.Value <= 30 Then
    c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else: c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Which hides every column other then the named ones but I can't get it to sort the data after this

I've tried to findcolumn/selectcolumn and sort but for some reason the macro seems to run and not actually sort

Also tried recording macro but as the columns move the code keeps defining the columns to sort as e.g. "D:D" or "AB:AB" however it might not always be in these columns so I need to SEARCH FOR THE HEADER then sort

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What type of "robot" do you mean?  (this is a very general term.)  Also, are you able to get this to sort how you want it **manually**? (without VBA?)

Comment: Select case c.Value would be easier syntax to read IMO And sort how? Asc? Desc?

Comment: Yes - I can sort the data manually the robot is basically reading a lot of viscosity and pH of final products but it throws up so many columns that we don't need - it exports everything onto excel but has many useless columns that we hide such as conductivity/wait times/correction factor ect.

Comment: And sorry QHarr sort Ascending or Decending shouldn't matter much to me as I need to search for 'Viscosity' in the 'Count' column and then take my readings from there but if the data is sorted I can just scroll across

Comment: Where is the code you have tried for doing the sorting?

Comment: This is just the sort of job that the PowerQuery tools built into Excel (under "Get Data" on the "Data" tab) are really good at, cleaning up data and removing unwanted columns without needing to use VBA. There is a bit of a learning curve to get up to speed, but the investment of time is well worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if something like this works for you...

The code assumes that there is no blank column in between the data set.

```
Sub SortColumns()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lc As Long
Dim vKeys()
lc = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
For i = lc To 1 Step -1
    If Columns(i).Hidden = False Then
        j = j + 1
        ReDim Preserve vKeys(1 To j)
        vKeys(j) = Cells(2, i).Address
    End If
Next i
'vKeys(4) --> First visible column from left
'vKeys(3) --> Second visible column from left
'vKeys(2) --> Third visible column from left
'vKeys(1) --> Fourth visible column from left
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range(vKeys(4)), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range(vKeys(3)), order2:=xlAscending, key3:=Range(vKeys(2)), order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range(vKeys(1)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that seems to work added on to the end of my macro!

Comment: @Hamster244 That's how it was supposed to work. Glad it worked as desired. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.